# Surface integral over hemisphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

It is given vector field $v(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} -x^3-2y \\ 3y^5z^6 \\ 3y^6z^5-z^4 \end{pmatrix} $

Evaluate the surface integral over the hemisphere F, which is defined by $z≥0$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$
Integral is defined as:

$\int_{\partial F}^{} \! v \cdot \, dx $

**What I did:**

I used spherical coordinates and I calculated $\nabla \times v=(0,0,2)$

Now I wanted to calculate the following integral,

$\int_{0}^{2} \! \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2} } \! \int_{0}^{2\pi } \! r^2sin\theta (0,0,2) \, d\theta \, d\varphi  \, dr$

But I dont get the right solution. Can someone help me with this? 
P.S. I am also confused why is in the integral, they gave, $dx$?

Comment: It is not dx, it should be dF.

Comment: If there is a model solution or answer, it is handy to include it in your question.

Comment: Here is the same example, only different numbers that I have solution. But when I try to solve on the same way I did above I cant get the right solution. $v(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} -3y-x \\ 4y^3z^4 \\ 4y^4z^3-3z \end{pmatrix} $ $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$. I calculated $\nabla \times v=(0,0,3)$ And now I have integral $\int_{0}^{4} \! \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2} } \! \int_{0}^{2\pi } \! r^2sin\theta (0,0,3) \, d\theta \, d\varphi  \, dr\neq 48 \pi $ .  So right solution for this example is $48 \pi$.

Comment: Why are you computing the curl ($\nabla \times$) of the vector field?

Comment: I tried to solve it with stokes' theorem.

Comment: But Stokes' theorem converts the **surface integral** of _the curl of a vector field_ to a **line integral** of the vector field itself (over the boundary of the surface); so then you would need to consider the given vector field _as the curl_ of another vector field (you would have to find). Alternatively, you could use the _Divergence theorem_ to transform the surface integral over the given vector field into a **triple integral** of the divergence of the vector field (compensating for the $z=0$-bottom of the sphere). I did a quick calculation but didn't end up with $48\pi$ though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me clarify the notations for you: $\int_{\partial F} v\cdot dx$ should be $\int_{\partial F} \mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{v}=(-x^3-2y,3y^5z^6,3y^6z^5-z^4)$ and $d\mathbf{x}=(dx,dy,dz)$. The integral, in its clearest form, is: $$\int_{\partial F} (-x^3-2y)dx+(3y^5z^6)dy+(3y^6z^5-z^4)dz.$$

Solution I (Stokes' theorem): $$\int_{\partial F} \mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{x}=\int_F \nabla\times \mathbf{v}\cdot n\,dS,$$ where $\nabla \times \mathbf{v}=(0,0,2)$ and $n$ is the unit outward-pointing normal to the surface $n=\frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\frac{1}{2}(x,y,z)$.

Use the parametrisation $\varphi:U=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq 4\}\to F$, given by $\varphi(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2})$. Then $$D\varphi(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\\ \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} & \frac{-y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\end{pmatrix}=:(v_1\,\, v_2)$$ We then find $$dS(v_1,v_2)=\det(n,v_1,v_2)=\frac{1}{2}\det\begin{pmatrix}x & 1 & 0 \\ y & 0 & 1\\ \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} & \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} & \frac{-y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\end{pmatrix}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}.$$ Finally, $$\begin{align}\int_{\partial F} \mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{x}
&=\int_F \nabla\times \mathbf{v}\cdot n\,dS\\
&=\int_U [(0,0,2)\cdot \frac{1}{2}(x,y,\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2})] \frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\\
&=2\int_U 1\\
&=2\,\text{area}(U)\\
&=2\pi (2^2)\\
&=8\pi.\end{align}$$

Solution II: Note that on the boundary $\partial F=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=4\,\text{and}\, z=0\}$, the integral reduces to $$\int_{\partial F} (-x^3-2y)dx.$$ Use the parametrisation $\phi(t):[0,2\pi]\to \partial F$ given by $\phi(t)=(2\cos t,2\sin t)$. Then $D\phi(t)=(-2\sin t,2\cos t)$ and $dx=-2\sin t\, dt$. Hence the integral is $$\int_0^{2\pi} (-(2\cos t)^3-2(2\sin t))(-2\sin t)\,dt=8\pi.$$

Solution III (Stokes' theorem with differential forms): Use the same parametrisation $\varphi$ as in solution I. Given the vector field $\mathbf{v}$, there is an associated differential form $$\omega=(-x^3-2y)dx+(3y^5z^6)dy+(3y^6z^5-z^4)dz.$$ $$\begin{align}\int_{\partial F} \mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{x}
&=\int_F \nabla\times \mathbf{v}\cdot n\,dS\\
&=\int_F d\omega\\
&=\int_U 2dx\wedge dy\\
&=\int_U 2\begin{vmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{vmatrix}\\
&=\int_U 2\\
&=2\,\text{area}(U)\\
&=8\pi.\end{align}$$

Solution IV: Let $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq 4\}$, $C=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=4\}$. Then $C=\partial D=\partial F$. $$\int_{C=\partial F=\partial D} \mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{x}=\int_D \nabla\times \mathbf{v}\cdot n\,dS=\int_D (0,0,2)\cdot (0,0,1)\,dS=2\,\text{area}(D)=8\pi$$ since $(0,0,1)$ is a unit normal to $D$.

To sum up, the above solutions follow from the following identities, each of which is a special case of the [generalised Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem). $$\begin{align}\int_{\partial F} \mathbf{v}\cdot d\mathbf{x}&\stackrel{I,IV}{=}\int_F \nabla\times \mathbf{v}\cdot n\,dS\\
&\stackrel{II}{=}\int_{\partial F} \omega\\
&\stackrel{III}{=}\int_F d\omega
\end{align}$$